# android pull to refresh listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview, refresh

I retrieve some data from the server and populate them into a listview. I want to implement pull to refresh in my listview but there's error with my app.  I use a library written by other people for the pull to refresh function.

Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
TextView ver;
TextView name;
TextView api;
Button Btngetdata;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_API = "api";

JSONArray android = null;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ((PullToRefreshListView)list).setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        public void onRefresh() {
            // Do work to refresh the list here.
             new JSONParse().execute();
        }
    });
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new JSONParse().execute();



        }
    });



}



private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
         name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
         api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();




    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        /* try {
             Thread.sleep(2000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             ;
         }*/
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         ((PullToRefreshListView) list).onRefreshComplete();

         try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String api = c.getString(TAG_API);




                // Adding value HashMap key => value


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_API, api);

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                                R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);


                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         String namee = oslist.get(position).get("name");
                         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, New.class);
                         intent.putExtra("key", namee);
                         startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     }
}

}
```

Here's the pull to refresh code:

```
public class PullToRefreshListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

private static final int TAP_TO_REFRESH = 1;
private static final int PULL_TO_REFRESH = 2;
private static final int RELEASE_TO_REFRESH = 3;
private static final int REFRESHING = 4;

private static final String TAG = "PullToRefreshListView";

private OnRefreshListener mOnRefreshListener;

/**
 * Listener that will receive notifications every time the list scrolls.
 */
private OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private RelativeLayout mRefreshView;
private TextView mRefreshViewText;
private ImageView mRefreshViewImage;
private ProgressBar mRefreshViewProgress;
private TextView mRefreshViewLastUpdated;

private int mCurrentScrollState;
private int mRefreshState;

private RotateAnimation mFlipAnimation;
private RotateAnimation mReverseFlipAnimation;

private int mRefreshViewHeight;
private int mRefreshOriginalTopPadding;
private int mLastMotionY;

private boolean mBounceHack;

public PullToRefreshListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public PullToRefreshListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    // Load all of the animations we need in code rather than through XML
    mFlipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, -180,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    mFlipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mFlipAnimation.setDuration(250);
    mFlipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mReverseFlipAnimation = new RotateAnimation(-180, 0,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    mReverseFlipAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    mReverseFlipAnimation.setDuration(250);
    mReverseFlipAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mRefreshView = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.pull_to_refresh_header, this, false);
    mRefreshViewText =
        (TextView) mRefreshView.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_text);
    mRefreshViewImage =
        (ImageView) mRefreshView.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_image);
    mRefreshViewProgress =
        (ProgressBar) mRefreshView.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_progress);
    mRefreshViewLastUpdated =
        (TextView) mRefreshView.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_updated_at);

    mRefreshViewImage.setMinimumHeight(50);
    mRefreshView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickRefreshListener());
    mRefreshOriginalTopPadding = mRefreshView.getPaddingTop();

    mRefreshState = TAP_TO_REFRESH;

    addHeaderView(mRefreshView);

    super.setOnScrollListener(this);

    measureView(mRefreshView);
    mRefreshViewHeight = mRefreshView.getMeasuredHeight();
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    setSelection(1);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    setSelection(1);
}

/**
 * Set the listener that will receive notifications every time the list
 * scrolls.
 * 
 * @param l The scroll listener. 
 */
@Override
public void setOnScrollListener(AbsListView.OnScrollListener l) {
    mOnScrollListener = l;
}

/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when this list should be refreshed.
 * 
 * @param onRefreshListener The callback to run.
 */
public void setOnRefreshListener(OnRefreshListener onRefreshListener) {
    mOnRefreshListener = onRefreshListener;
}

/**
 * Set a text to represent when the list was last updated. 
 * @param lastUpdated Last updated at.
 */
public void setLastUpdated(CharSequence lastUpdated) {
    if (lastUpdated != null) {
        mRefreshViewLastUpdated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefreshViewLastUpdated.setText(lastUpdated);
    } else {
        mRefreshViewLastUpdated.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int y = (int) event.getY();
    mBounceHack = false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!isVerticalScrollBarEnabled()) {
                setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            }
            if (getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && mRefreshState != REFRESHING) {
                if ((mRefreshView.getBottom() >= mRefreshViewHeight
                        || mRefreshView.getTop() >= 0)
                        && mRefreshState == RELEASE_TO_REFRESH) {
                    // Initiate the refresh
                    mRefreshState = REFRESHING;
                    prepareForRefresh();
                    onRefresh();
                } else if (mRefreshView.getBottom() < mRefreshViewHeight
                        || mRefreshView.getTop() <= 0) {
                    // Abort refresh and scroll down below the refresh view
                    resetHeader();
                    setSelection(1);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mLastMotionY = y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            applyHeaderPadding(event);
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void applyHeaderPadding(MotionEvent ev) {
    // getHistorySize has been available since API 1
    int pointerCount = ev.getHistorySize();

    for (int p = 0; p < pointerCount; p++) {
        if (mRefreshState == RELEASE_TO_REFRESH) {
            if (isVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled()) {
                setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            }

            int historicalY = (int) ev.getHistoricalY(p);

            // Calculate the padding to apply, we divide by 1.7 to
            // simulate a more resistant effect during pull.
            int topPadding = (int) (((historicalY - mLastMotionY)
                    - mRefreshViewHeight) / 1.7);

            mRefreshView.setPadding(
                    mRefreshView.getPaddingLeft(),
                    topPadding,
                    mRefreshView.getPaddingRight(),
                    mRefreshView.getPaddingBottom());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the header padding back to original size.
 */
private void resetHeaderPadding() {
    mRefreshView.setPadding(
            mRefreshView.getPaddingLeft(),
            mRefreshOriginalTopPadding,
            mRefreshView.getPaddingRight(),
            mRefreshView.getPaddingBottom());
}

/**
 * Resets the header to the original state.
 */
private void resetHeader() {
    if (mRefreshState != TAP_TO_REFRESH) {
        mRefreshState = TAP_TO_REFRESH;

        resetHeaderPadding();

        // Set refresh view text to the pull label
        mRefreshViewText.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_tap_label);
        // Replace refresh drawable with arrow drawable
        mRefreshViewImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pulltorefresh_arrow);
        // Clear the full rotation animation
        mRefreshViewImage.clearAnimation();
        // Hide progress bar and arrow.
        mRefreshViewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRefreshViewProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void measureView(View child) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = child.getLayoutParams();
    if (p == null) {
        p = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(0,
            0 + 0, p.width);
    int lpHeight = p.height;
    int childHeightSpec;
    if (lpHeight > 0) {
        childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    } else {
        childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    }
    child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // When the refresh view is completely visible, change the text to say
    // "Release to refresh..." and flip the arrow drawable.
    if (mCurrentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL
            && mRefreshState != REFRESHING) {
        if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
            mRefreshViewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if ((mRefreshView.getBottom() >= mRefreshViewHeight + 20
                    || mRefreshView.getTop() >= 0)
                    && mRefreshState != RELEASE_TO_REFRESH) {
                mRefreshViewText.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_release_label);
                mRefreshViewImage.clearAnimation();
                mRefreshViewImage.startAnimation(mFlipAnimation);
                mRefreshState = RELEASE_TO_REFRESH;
            } else if (mRefreshView.getBottom() < mRefreshViewHeight + 20
                    && mRefreshState != PULL_TO_REFRESH) {
                mRefreshViewText.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_pull_label);
                if (mRefreshState != TAP_TO_REFRESH) {
                    mRefreshViewImage.clearAnimation();
                    mRefreshViewImage.startAnimation(mReverseFlipAnimation);
                }
                mRefreshState = PULL_TO_REFRESH;
            }
        } else {
            mRefreshViewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resetHeader();
        }
    } else if (mCurrentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING
            && firstVisibleItem == 0
            && mRefreshState != REFRESHING) {
        setSelection(1);
        mBounceHack = true;
    } else if (mBounceHack && mCurrentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
        setSelection(1);
    }

    if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
        mOnScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem,
                visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    mCurrentScrollState = scrollState;

    if (mCurrentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        mBounceHack = false;
    }

    if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
        mOnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
    }
}

public void prepareForRefresh() {
    resetHeaderPadding();

    mRefreshViewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // We need this hack, otherwise it will keep the previous drawable.
    mRefreshViewImage.setImageDrawable(null);
    mRefreshViewProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Set refresh view text to the refreshing label
    mRefreshViewText.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_refreshing_label);

    mRefreshState = REFRESHING;
}

public void onRefresh() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRefresh");

    if (mOnRefreshListener != null) {
        mOnRefreshListener.onRefresh();
    }
}

/**
 * Resets the list to a normal state after a refresh.
 * @param lastUpdated Last updated at.
 */
public void onRefreshComplete(CharSequence lastUpdated) {
    setLastUpdated(lastUpdated);
    onRefreshComplete();
}

/**
 * Resets the list to a normal state after a refresh.
 */
public void onRefreshComplete() {        
    Log.d(TAG, "onRefreshComplete");

    resetHeader();

    // If refresh view is visible when loading completes, scroll down to
    // the next item.
    if (getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
        invalidateViews();
        setSelection(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Invoked when the refresh view is clicked on. This is mainly used when
 * there's only a few items in the list and it's not possible to drag the
 * list.
 */
private class OnClickRefreshListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mRefreshState != REFRESHING) {
            prepareForRefresh();
            onRefresh();
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when list should be
 * refreshed.
 */
public interface OnRefreshListener {
    /**
     * Called when the list should be refreshed.
     * <p>
     * A call to {@link PullToRefreshListView #onRefreshComplete()} is
     * expected to indicate that the refresh has completed.
     */
    public void onRefresh();
}
}
```

Here's the logcat error when i run my app:

```
 10-20 05:26:12.867: E/AndroidRuntime(2633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zanqi.testtest/com.zanqi.testtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zanqi.testtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing NullPointerException?

Comment: What is line 67 in MainActivity.java? How does your layout look? Easiest way is for you to tell us line 67. Might be wrong IDs in the layout or other things.

Comment: line 67 is to Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing list(instance of PullToRefreshListView) please add following line in your oncreate method of Activity

```
list = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewid);
```

then call setOnRefreshListener . Also initialize other variables which you want to use.

Comment: it doestn't work i have  list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  in onPost execute

Comment: it won't work at all if you keep it in onPostExecute. You need to keep it in onCreate method after setContentView Call.